# How many uGUI elements is too many on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, canvas, unity-game-engine

According to this page, https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-basic.html, too many UnityGUI elements is considered bad, but what is too many if my game runs entirely on the canvas?  At the moment, my UI will contain about 100 objects, most are buttons and 80 of the objects, use full or portions of 3 textures to display the objects.

Does this mean that uGUI cannot or should not be used for iOS games?

Comment: Test your game on device and use the profiler to see what kind of optimizations you may need to consider. My experience is that it is totally different from game to game. I would not ditch uGUI without testing it first in the real environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That post is talking about something totally **different** and you are confusing yourself with `uGUI` and `UnityGUI/IMGUI`.

`UnityGUI/IMGUI` is an old UI System. That's what the article is talking about. Don't use it. I've been warning new users about that too due and they use it due to old tutorials they are following.

The **only** time you should use this is when you are writing an `Editor` script to test your game in the `Editor` but this should never be deployed to your mobile device or used as a standalone build.

*How to know when you are using `UnityGUI/IMGUI` or which tutorials to avoid?* When you see `OnGUI()` anywhere in the code, then stop.

The latest UI System in Unity is simply called `uGUI`. I don't know if the name has changed but this was the original name when it came out. It is only available from `Unity 4.6` and above. You can find this from the `UnityEngine.UI;` namespace.

[This](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UICanvas.html) is the link you should be reading for the new UI and [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui) for UI tutorials.

> Does this mean that uGUI cannot or should not be used for iOS games?

`uGUI` should be used for all your UI work.Again, I am **not** talking about the `UI` from the article. I am talking about the `UI` from the `UnityEngine.UI;` namespace.

> my UI will contain about 100 objects, most are buttons and 80 of the
>   objects

`uGUI` uses `Canvas` to drive the `UI` and they are parent GameObject of `UI` components.. You may want to separate them into different `Canvas`. For example, `MainMenu Canvas`, `PauseMenu Canvas`, `GamePlay Canvas`.... Under each `Canvas`, you can then have your components such as `Buttons` and `Texts`.

When you are on the main menu, you enable the `MainMenu Canvas` and disable the rest. You can do this for your other Canvas in your scene depending on the mode of your game. I can't think of any scenario where you need `80` `UI` components at the-same time, on the scene. You must separate them.

Comment: Awesome thank you ... I had no idea that UnityGUI and uGUI were different.